# UI layout of screen in wpf distorts on bigger screen

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have designed my UI in WPF(xaml) but when i run it on screen bigger than the size of my desktop, the screen distorts,how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share the xaml code. In general it happens when you hard code the width and height of controls in xaml. If used "Auto" property for both Height and Width the controls will align themselves automatically depending on screen size or resolution.